# What is the significance of the pyramids?

Tags: 1899

In *1899*, a large gray-black pyramid appears in the simulations in various forms: as the first lock to escape the simulation, in a gigantic form outside Maura's father's office, and so forth. Perhaps the most interesting pyramid is the alchemical symbol for earth, , which appears in numerous places throughout the simulation.

Now, the main simulation occurs in an ocean, whereas the reality is that of a spaceship traveling through the void (as far as we know...). None of these seem to have a clear link to pyramids or to the element of earth. Further, since Maura made the simulation, as far as we know, she must have put the pyramids there intentionally. What is the significance of this symbolism?

Comment: Other (triangle) alchemist symbols with  Earth are;  Water,  Fire and  Air.

Comment: @Oni True, but it is the Earth one that appears in the series.

Comment: @Adamant unsure if what (if any) significance there is to it but Water and Fire also appear

Answer (score 2):

Very much partial or just vague ideas (beyond just pyramids) that didn't fit into a comment:

The pyramid (and the key, note the new version of code remains a pyramid), for much of the series, serve as the means to exit the simulation.

If Maura is the originator of the simulation then she has literally littered her creation with reminders, known only to her, of where or what the codes to exit are. Aside from the Captain noticing the shipping company logo (also Earth), no other character notices, nor mentions it if they do see, the same symbols put into everything on board the ship and each other.

You never get close to the giant pyramid, it seems to represent, as a big reminder, the smaller key version that Elliot possesses. Also, the pyramid signifies the importance of life after death for the ancient Egyptians. Pyramids may have been viewed as a way to send the soul of the dead pharaoh directly to the home of the gods. These structures were also a symbol of power and authority.

The symbol for Earth (less pyramid, more upside down triangle) serves as home, more important once you get to the end and realise its a mission of survival, and that they have actually left Earth, the home planet, behind. Heading towards a set of coordinates (that haven't revealed anything yet).

Given the themes, its likely that the ending of 1899 is yet another simulation.

Lots of props or items seen away from the ship simulation, including the music tracks playing at the end, seem to firmly root us in the late 20th century, and not the far sci-fi future at all.

The way in which Maura's brother is said to have taken over the project does not feel like it sits within a sci-fi scenario, but rather one of the present (Like a boardroom coup).

Daniels memory room, seems to be set in the present day as well, that is, it is clearly not in 1899 nor is it set in the future.

Another note for 2099 being another simulation: Ciaran must be watching, much like how Henry was portrayed originally as watching, for him to have sent a message at just the right time for Maura to read it. (Alternatively, if real, then yes, he is just monitoring from the ships control room..)

Reference links:

https://www.heavenofhorror.com/features/netflix-series-1899-season-1-ending-explained/

https://www.denofgeek.com/tv/1899-explained-ending-twists/

https://screenrant.com/1899-netflix-ending-explained/

https://www.express.co.uk/showbiz/tv-radio/1696607/What-is-pyramid-1899

https://thecinemaholic.com/what-is-the-pyramid-in-1899-explained/

https://dmtalkies.com/1899-season-1-ending-explained-2022-german-netflix-series-baran-bo-oda/

https://1899-netflix.fandom.com/wiki/Pyramid

https://1899-netflix.fandom.com/wiki/The_Pyramid_(episode)

https://collider.com/1899-season-1-unanswered-questions/

https://hu.ign.com/1899-1-evad/81929/news/1899-spoilerek-megmagyarazzuk-a-vegkifejletet-es-hogy-mit-varunk-a-2-evadtol

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9319668/trivia?ref_=ttgf_sa_1

> The show's triangle symbolism comes from alchemy. The four upright, inverted and crossed-thru variations of the equilateral triangle represent the four basic elements of earth, air, fire, and water. The shipping company's logo features the inverted-crossed triangle, representing earth. The four symbols are used extensively throughout the show's production design, appearing on: clothes (particularly Ling Yi's geisha robe), jewellery, doors, wall and floor panels, the radio room's Morse code ticker, tattoos, and of course the mysterious tetrahedron and Solace's "puzzle box".

And 2099 Maura has the Earth symbol tattooed behind her ear like her son did:

[image]

1899 and pyramids also reminds me of La Pyramide de Triboulet (Triboulet's Pyramid), a French short film by Georges Melies, released in that year, known for his pioneering use of special effects in the early days of cinema.

The short film is set in an ornate room, with the jester Triboulet using magic to sprout nine men from a trunk, seating them in the form of a pyramid, and then magically turning them into women.

Melies was known for burning and destroying a lot of his films in 1923, La Pyramide de Triboulet being among them. Once *considered lost, it was found again* in 2007...

[image]

Of course, take the above with a pinch of salt. As I say, I couldn't fit it in a comment...